# Azure Data Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to handle ingestion or which way – everyday getting same amount data (SAY 10 GB). Some unchanged, some modified, some new, but you must insert only modified and new, reject all unchanged. Which tool/process we are going to use in ADF.

Comment: You need to add way more details to your question before it can be answered

Answer (score 0):

you need to do 2 things

1. maybe try SCD (slowly changing dimension), add a new column to differ new rows and modified rows from unchanged rows, maybe consider adding a column (modified-date, flag or so).
2. create a lookup activity, click on it, in source option , click on input -> then in query bar, paste your command (lets say select all the rows that insert_date is different than modified date )
   pay attention that the lookup activity is limited to 5000 rows.
   **link to scd** :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

The process depends on the type and source of the data.

- If the source is **Azure blob** and you want to copy new and modified files, then you can use the copy activity for it.
  In the source of copy activity go to Filter by last modified and give
  `@adddays(utcnow(),-1)` at start time and `@utcnow()` at the end time.

  [image]

Add a trigger to this by which you can copy new/updated files every 24 hours.

- If the source is **SQL Database**, you can try the approach of adding a new column that was suggested by **@Sally Dabbah**.
- If you are using **Azure SQL Database with managed instance**, you can use **CDC (Change Data Capture)** in it which captures the data change for every row.

  Please refer to this [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal) which has step by step
  explanation about this process.